# How do you apply an algorithm individually to an array with many graphs

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, graphs-and-networks

I have and array with many graphs to which I want to apply an algorithm (below) to each graph in an array that contains all my graphs.

```
(* g & g1 represent the directed graphs*)
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 2 -> 8, 7 -> 9, 9 -> 10, 9 -> 11, 9 -> 12, 8 -> 13, 5 -> 14}];
g1= = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 2 -> 8, 7 -> 9, 9 -> 10, 9 -> 11, 9 -> 12, 8 -> 13, 5 -> 14, 14->13, 14->15, 15->16, 1->17, 1->8}];

(* I define an array with all the graphs*)
allgraphs={g,g1};

(* I define f11 function to use later in the algorithm*)
f11[n_] := n == 0;
```

(*Now, I'm especially having trouble here: I've played around with Map and putting a Table within a Table but my problem is always that I am not able to iterate x[Distributed] for every graph in my array of graphs!*)

```
Table[Probability[x == k,  x \[Distributed] VertexDegree[g]], {k, 
   Max[VertexDegree[g]]}];
```

Aside: I've tried things like to iterate on all graphs: 
Table[Probability[x == k,  x [Distributed] VertexDegree[j]], {k, 
       Max[VertexDegree[j]]}, {j, allgraphs];
And obviously it doesn't like doing that iteration.

```
(* I create an array that will list the vertex degrees from 1 to the max degree of the graph*)
Table[a, {a, 1, Max[VertexDegree[g]]}];

(* Combining the two arrays gives me a form {x,y} *)
Table[{%[[i]], %%[[i]]}, {i, Max[VertexDegree[ac]]}];
(* Here I call on my f11 function defined above to delete values with degree=0 because it gives me trouble when I try to plot the log-log form*)
DeleteCases[%, {x_, y_} /; f11[x] \[Or] f11[y]];
Log@%;

(* I define gPlot here, because later I want to populate a grid with the algorithm run on all of my graphs. Currently I copy and paste "gPlot" into my grid and that's why I define the name here*)
gPlot = ListPlot[%, PlotLabel -> "ACC", Filling -> Axis, 
   PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledCircle]", 8, Black], 
   Joined -> {True}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, Mesh -> Full, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 3.5}, {0, -6}}];
```

So there is it. I want to be able to run the algorithm on every graph in the array allgraphs, so I know I need some sort of iterator but I'm not sure the terminology of the correct process.

Comment: Hi! Can you narrow your problem down a bit and remove antything that is not essential for the reproduction/solution of your task? A shorter description (if possible) may help getting more answers.

Comment: Regarding your "obviously it doesn't like doing that" snippet: the *outermost* iterator should be given *first*. Like this: `Table[stuff, {j, allgraphs}, {k, Max[VertexDegree[j]]}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plotOne[g_Graph] := Module[{probs, purgedTab, r = Range@Max@VertexDegree@g}, 
  probs = {#, Probability[x == #, x \[Distributed] VertexDegree[g]]} & /@ r;
  purgedTab = DeleteCases[probs, {x_, y_} /; x y == 0];
  ListLinePlot[Log@purgedTab, Filling -> Axis,
               Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Black],
               PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, -4}}]]

 GraphicsRow[plotOne /@ allgraphs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I'm hardly sure that I have understood your question fully, but does this give you the result that you want?

```
Table[Probability[x == k, x \[Distributed] VertexDegree[j]], {j, 
  allgraphs}, {k, Max[VertexDegree[j]]}]
```

You need to specify the `j` iterator first, as the specification of `k` depends on `j`.

On a more general note, I would say that if I want to apply an algorithm to a list of elements of some kind, then I would

1. Make an algorithm that acts on one element, `f[e_]:=Block[...]`
2. Map that function onto a (perhaps complicated) list of elements

If the list is as simple as yours, `list = {e1,e2,...,ek}` then the shorthand way to apply this function to all the elements is

```
f /@ list
```